# is there a method in java for drawing a circle with double variables for its center?

Tags: java, jframe

here i'm trying to draw a circle using drawOval method and I want to move  it on the screen with a specific velocity. but i have a problem with double variables for the velocity.for example when vx=0.25 and vy=0 the circle is just stuck on its place.
sorry for my bad English though.

here is the java code that i'm using

```
 int x=0 , y=0;
 @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    move();
    g.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    repaint();
}
public void move() {
    x+=0.25;
    y+=0.25;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just have `x` and `y` as doubles, then cast them to ints before giving to `drawOval`?

Answer (score 3):

- You should **not** call `move` from the `paintComponent` method! You never know when this method will be called, and thus, you cannot control the movement speed properly.
- You should **not** call `repaint` from the `paintComponent` method! **Never**. This will send the painting system into an endless cycle of repaint operations!

---

Regarding the question:

There is a method for drawing arbitrary shapes based on `double` coordinates. This is also covered and explained extensively in the [2D Graphics Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/). The key is to use the `Shape` interface. For your particular example, the relevant part of the code is this:

```
private double x = 0;
private double y = 0;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
{
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;

    double radius = 5;
    g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(
        x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2));
}
```

That is, you create an `Ellipse2D` instance, and then just draw it.

Here is an MVCE, showing what you're probably trying to accomplish:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PaintWithDouble
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        PaintWithDoublePanel p = new PaintWithDoublePanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(p);
        startMoveThread(p);

        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void startMoveThread(PaintWithDoublePanel p)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
            while (true)
            {
                p.move();
                p.repaint();
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }
}

class PaintWithDoublePanel extends JPanel
{
    private double x = 0;
    private double y = 0;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        double radius = 5;
        g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(
            x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2));

        g.drawString("At " + x + ", " + y, 10, 30);
    }

    public void move()
    {
        x += 0.05;
        y += 0.05;
    }

}
```

---

Edited in response to the comment (and to clarify some things that have been said in other answers) :

While it is technically correct to say that there are "only whole pixels", and there "is no pixel with coordinates (0.3, 1.8)", this does not mean that fractional coordinates will not affect the final appearance of the rendered output. Every topic becomes a science when you're studying it long enough. Particularly, a *lot* of research went into the question of how to improve the visual appearance of rendered output, going beyond what you can achieve with a trivial [Bresenham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) or so. An entry point for further research could be the article about [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering).

In many cases, as usual, there are trade-offs between the appearance and the drawing performance. As for Java and its 2D drawing capabilities, these trade-offs are mostly controlled via the `RenderingHints` class. For example, there is the [`RenderingHints#VALUE_STROKE_PURE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/RenderingHints.html#VALUE_STROKE_PURE) that enables subpixel rendering. The effect is shown in this screen capture:

[image: Subpixel]

The slider is used to change the y-offset of the rightmost point of a horizontal line by -3 to +3 pixels. In the upper left, you see a line, rendered as-it-is. In the middle, you see the line magnified by a factor of 8, to better show the effect: The pixels are filled with different opacities, depending on *how much of the pixel is covered by an idealized, 1 pixel wide line*.

While it's certainly the case that this is not relevant for most application cases, it might be worth noting here.

The following is an MCVE that was used for the screen capture:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PaintWithDoubleMagnified
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        PaintWithDoubleMagnifiedPanel p = new PaintWithDoubleMagnifiedPanel();
        f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 50);
        slider.addChangeListener(e -> {
            int value = slider.getValue();
            double relative = -0.5 + value / 100.0;
            p.setY(relative * 6);
        });
        f.getContentPane().add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class PaintWithDoubleMagnifiedPanel extends JPanel
{
    private double y = 0;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) gr;

        g.drawString("At " + y, 10, 20);
        paintLine(g);

        BufferedImage image = paintIntoImage();
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
        g.scale(8.0, 8.0);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    }

    public void setY(double y)
    {
        this.y = y;
        repaint();
    }

    private void paintLine(Graphics2D g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);

        Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(
            10, 30, 50, 30 + y);
        g.draw(line);

    }

    private BufferedImage paintIntoImage()
    {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
            100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        paintLine(g);
        g.dispose();
        return image;
    }

}
```

Comment: Agree with algorithm and using another Api (`Graphics2D`), `double` is allowed as parameter. But rendering system is the same (a pixel is one by each other on x if distance is 1). Said other consider the following ` for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        {
           g.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double( 100+x+i/10000 - radius, 100+y+1/10000 - radius, radius * 10, radius * 10));
        }`. This do not involve rendering 10.000 ellipses on distinct spots on graph. It's render as 1(actually few), even if there are 10.000 on distinct coordinates.

Comment: Actually it's i/10000.0 but the results are the same

Comment: Thx. for answer it's bring additional knowledge for myself. But it's not quit my question or maybe din't understand properly your response. Better assume that (0.5,1) is a subpixel and wanted also display but as pixel. More do not want to magnify via scale. So instead of (0,0),(0.5,0),(1,0) should have display (0,0),(1,0),(2,0). That translation can be done with methods (settings) for g2d ?  So (0.5) will be visible on screen as (1,0) with out do any other settings_magnify.(as distinct pixel and not overlap on 0 or 1).

Comment: @TraianGEICU I'm not entirely sure whether I understood your commend correctly, but of course, it is not unusual to store `double` values and then simply cast them to `int` in order to call `drawLine` or `drawOval`. I just wanted to mention that 1. it is possible to use `double` coordinates and 2. it may make a difference in the visual appearance (although the latter may only be relevant in very few cases). Particularly, if *efficiency* is your primary concern, then casting to `int` and using `Graphics` is likely to be the fastest.

Comment: Thx. again. 1. agree, 2. agree. Me just wanted to say that i could render what double it's needed as int but with appropriate translation even with standard  methods from Graphics Api (better said ranges of doubles)

Answer (score 0):

First notice that rendering system is using int as arguments for each pixel.

So if `p1` is near `p2` on x axis then
`p1(x,y)` and `p2(x+1,y)` 
eg:(0,0) and (1,0) 
You do not have something in the middle like (0.5,1) since no pixels.

That why Graphics api is using int for (x,y) coordinates.
[Graphics api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

If you wanted to consider also double you have to adapt the default coordinates systems to fit your needs.(cannot render all double there in individual pixels, need to group them in categories)

Eg. say want to place x_points : `0, 0.5, 1`

So `0->0`, `0.5(double)->1(int)` , `1->2`

 Other pixels could map as `0.2->1`, `0.7->2` , `-0.9->0`

One rule map consider all double range (better say `in (-0.5,1]`)
can be 
 `-0.5<d<=0 -> 0`,`0<d<=0.5 -> 1`, `0.5<d<=1 -> 2` where `d=input_x`(double) 

 That means you adjust the coordinates systems to fit your needs

> is there a method in java for drawing a circle with double variables for its center?

NO(using standard Graphics api). Have just what api is provided, but you could render what ever input you wanted (even based on double) by adjusting coordinates system.

```
class MyPaint extends JPanel
{

private double x = 0, y=0;
private int width = 30, height = 30;

//adjust coordinates system
//for x in [0,1] have [0,0.1,0.2,0.3 ..] 
//from no pixel between (0,1) to 9 pixels (0,0.1, ..,1)
//0->0,0.1->1,0.2->2,0.9->9,1->10
//in that way you have full control of rendering
private double scale_x = 0.1;
//same on y as x 
private double scale_y = 0.1;
//pixel scaled on x,y
//drawing with
private int xs,ys;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    xs = (int) (x/scale_x);
    ys = (int) (y/scale_y);
    g.drawString("Draw At: " + xs + ", " + ys + " From:" + x+","+y, 10, 30);
    g.drawOval(xs, ys, (int) (width/scale_x), (int) (height/scale_y));
}

public void move()
{
     //adjustments is better to be >= then scale(x or y) seen as absolute value
     //if need 0.01 to be display on individual pixel on x 
     //then modify scale_x = 0.01 (or even 0.001)
     x+=0.1;
     y+=0.5;
}
}
```